# loading dataset from csv file for keras in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use keras with tensorflow to train a network. I've my own digit dataset of myanmar language. I'm trying to develop myanmar digits recognition using neural network using python. Firstly i want to load dataset from labeled train dataset .csv file. and also to load dataset from unlabeled test dataset .csv file. Problem is how to load these dataset from those dataset file. Please help me in detail explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is example of loading csv file into dataframe and you can do data engineer part and go through the neural network model.

```
import pandas as pd
label = ['digit1_','digit2_'....]

for i in label:
      train_set = pd.read_csv(i + 'trainset.csv')

test_set = pd.read_csv('testset.csv')
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: I'm afraid `train_set` will end up simply being the last labeled digit in the training set because `train_set` is overridden for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just do,

```
train_set = pd.read_csv("train_set.csv")
```

and similarly for `test set` as well!